# custom input directive using ngModel does not update model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to use ngPattern in a custom input directive. To play around I have created the following directive at first:

```
myApp.directive('myInput', [function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: true,
        template:
            '<div>' +
            '  <input type="text" ng-model="val" ng-change="updateValue()" ng-pattern="/^-?(?:\d+|\d*\.(\d+)?)$/i">' +
            '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){     
            scope.updateValue = function(){
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.val);
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
                scope.val = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

I see in the debugger the value of `scope.val` is always undefined so the call `$setValue` has no effect. I have tried to remove the ng-pattern attribute but also then the update does not work.

What is wrong here? The plunkr can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZsRS2THKnu0tQ8N9r8Vs?p=preview), where *I bind to a model and not to a primitive!*

**Update**

It seems that calling `ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.val)` in the `scope.updateValue` has a strange result. If have a model like this:

```
scope.model = {
    'testValue' : 12
};
```

And I bind to `"model.testValue"` (as in the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZsRS2THKnu0tQ8N9r8Vs?p=preview)) then the model becomes an empty object `{}` after the execution of `ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.val)`.  Setting the value again in a normal input field will reset the `scope.model` variable to a sane object. To me this makes no sense. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution myself. I am not sure whether it is the best way to it but it works. I saw quite similar directives like my original version (in the sense how the data-binding is implemented), for example [jkuri.touchSpin](https://github.com/jkuri/ngTouchSpin).

The important thing was to keep a reference of the original `$render` function of the ngModelController and call this function after using `$setViewValue`.

But what worked for me in the end was this:

```
myApp.directive('myInput', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: true,
        template:
            '<div>' +
            '  <input type="text" ng-model="val" ng-change="updateValue()"  ng-pattern="regex" >' +
            '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
            var orignalRender = ngModelCtrl.$render;
            scope.regex = /^-?(?:\d+|\d*\.(\d+)?)$/i;
            ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
                scope.val = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
            };              
            scope.updateValue = function(){
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.val);
                orignalRender();
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Rule of thumb:

Whatever you pass to ng-model should have a . meaning you don't want to bind to primitives.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance

Comment: As you can see in the plunkr there is a ".", so I bind a model not a primitive.

Comment: I think he was referring to your ng-model in the template string, where you aren not using a "."